# Will non-USB 3 Lightning to Camera Adapter work for new iPhone Migration?

Tags: iphone, usb, migration

Will the [Lightning to USB Camera Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD821AM/A/lightning-to-usb-camera-adapter) (pictured below, with no additional Lightning port) work for the new iPhone Migration, where data is transferred from old to new iPhone via cable?

[image]

[Apple’s support page for migration](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210216#migration) links specifically to the [Lightning to USB 3 Camera Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MK0W2AM/A/lightning-to-usb-3-camera-adapter), which is visibly different with an additional female Lightning port. I currently have the older adapter, and am wondering:

- Will this older adapter work for iPhone Migration?
- If so, will the data transfer speed be capped to USB 2 speeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's support documents only list the "Lightning to USB 3 Camera Adapter" as compatible with this process. If you want to be guaranteed that it works - use that adapter.

You can test your old adapter without fear of breaking. If the "Lightning to USB Camera Adapter" works for you, it will be capped at USB 2 speeds, as it doesn't support higher speeds.